# Nothing Launches From Main Method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, implementation, program-entry-point

When I launch my program below from the 3 class files, nothing at all happens. It just displays an empty console. Am I missing some sort of implementation or something? It consists of the 3 class files and I have no error messages from the compiler. The program simply has to display each quiz question, the player answers and then gets their final score at the end. Thanks!

```
public class Question 
{
   private String question, answer;


   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets up the question with a default complexity.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public Question (String query, String result)
   {
      question = query;
      answer = result;

   }



   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the question.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String getQuestion()
   {
      return question;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the answer to this question.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String getAnswer()
   {
      return answer;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns true if the candidate answer matches the answer.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean answerCorrect (String candidateAnswer)
   {
      return answer.equals(candidateAnswer);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns this question (and its answer) as a string.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString()
   {
      return question + "\n" + answer;
   }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Quiz

{
private int score;
private Question[] questionHolder = new Question[25];
private int numQuestions;



public Quiz()
{
this.score = 0;
this.numQuestions = 0;

}

public void addQuestion (Question Q)
{
this.questionHolder[numQuestions++] = Q;
}

public int giveQuiz()

{

Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

String candidateAnswer;


scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();


for (int i = 0; i < numQuestions; i++)
{

candidateAnswer = scan.nextLine();
if (questionHolder.answerCorrect(candidateAnswer))
score++;
}
return getscore();
}
public int getscore()
{
return score;
}
public String toString()
{
return getscore() + "\n";
}

}

public class QuizTime

{
public static void main (String[] args)

{
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Initializes the variables.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Question Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8, Q9, Q10, Q11, Q12, Q13, Q14, Q15, Q16, Q17, Q18, Q19,
Q20, Q21, Q22, Q23, Q24, Q25;

Quiz T1;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Creates the question and answer and also sets its complexity value.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Q1 = new Question ("What is the capital of Virginia?", "Richmond");

Q2 = new Question ("Is an apple a Fruit or a vegetable?", "Fruit");

Q3 = new Question ("What continent is China in?", "Asia");

Q4 = new Question ("Is Germany in Europe or South America?", "Europe");

Q5 = new Question ("What color is a black bear?", "Black");

Q6 = new Question ("What is the capital of Arizona?", "Phoenix");

Q7 = new Question ("What do cows produce??", "Milk");

Q8 = new Question ("What ocean is closest to New York City?", "Atlantic");

Q9 = new Question ("What ocean surrounds Japan?", "Pacific");

Q10 = new Question ("What is the largest state in America?", "Alaska");

Q11 = new Question ("What is the smallest state?", "Deleware");

Q12 = new Question ("What is the most populated state?", "California");

Q13 = new Question ("What is instrument did Jascha Heifetz play?", "Violin");

Q14 = new Question ("Was Mozart a composer or a computer?", "Composer");

Q15 = new Question ("What is the largest country by area?", "Russia");

Q16 = new Question ("What is the most populated country?", "China");

Q17 = new Question ("What country did Pizza originate in?", "Italy");

Q18 = new Question ("What is the last name of the first American President?", "Washington");

Q19 = new Question ("What country borders America to the south?", "Mexico");

Q20 = new Question ("What island is 700 miles off the coast of NYC?", "Bermuda");

Q21 = new Question ("What city contains the Eiffel Tower?", "Paris");

Q22 = new Question ("Who wrote Romeo and Juliet?", "Shakespeare");

Q23 = new Question ("What swims in the ocean?", "Fish");

Q24 = new Question ("What is man's best friend?", "Dog");

Q25 = new Question ("What is another name for coffee and the language of this program?", "Java");


//--------------------------------------------------------------
//Adds the questions into quiz.
//--------------------------------------------------------------
T1= new Quiz();
T1.addQuestion(Q1);
T1.addQuestion(Q2);
T1.addQuestion(Q3);
T1.addQuestion(Q4);
T1.addQuestion(Q5);
T1.addQuestion(Q6);
T1.addQuestion(Q7);
T1.addQuestion(Q8);
T1.addQuestion(Q9);
T1.addQuestion(Q10);
T1.addQuestion(Q11);
T1.addQuestion(Q12);
T1.addQuestion(Q13);
T1.addQuestion(Q14);
T1.addQuestion(Q15);
T1.addQuestion(Q16);
T1.addQuestion(Q17);
T1.addQuestion(Q18);
T1.addQuestion(Q19);
T1.addQuestion(Q20);
T1.addQuestion(Q21);
T1.addQuestion(Q22);
T1.addQuestion(Q23);
T1.addQuestion(Q24);
T1.addQuestion(Q25);

//--------------------------------------------------------------
//Prints out the quizes.
//--------------------------------------------------------------
System.out.print(T1.giveQuiz());


}
}
```

Comment: Do use arrays, do indent, don't use lots of extra blank lines.

Comment: And use javadoc to document your methods, instead of your own custom syntax.

Comment: You know, you're not actually printing out the quiz questions. When you run your `main` method, are you also typing in the answers at the console?

Comment: I want it to print out each quiz question 1 by 1 and let the user answer them. When I type something the program crashes immediately.

Answer (score 4):

There is an error in this line

```
if (questionHolder.answerCorrect(candidateAnswer)) // questionHolder is an array
```

Since `questionHolder` is an array, you need to provide the index in the loop.

```
if (questionHolder[i].answerCorrect(candidateAnswer)) // like this, [i] - index
```

Also, the program starts, but waits for an input from the user. There is no SOP to indicate the user to input a value, thus making you think that it does nothing.

```
// Waiting for the user to input an integer value, but there is no SOP to intimate the 
// user about it, thus making it seem like doing nothing.
scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```

---

To ask the question to the user, print it in the `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numQuestions; i++) {
    System.out.println(questionHolder[i].getQuestion()); // Question is displayed to the user now. Answer accordingly.
    candidateAnswer = scan.nextLine();
    if (questionHolder[i].answerCorrect(candidateAnswer))
        score++;
}
```

Keeping this in mind, I feel that these 2 lines before the `for` loop in `giveQuiz()` are unnecessary.

```
// scan.nextInt();
// scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: I want it to print out each quiz question 1 by 1 and let the user answer them. When I type something the program crashes immediately. If I type an int and hit enter nothing happens either

Comment: The logic of your code isn't that though. It just takes in 20 answers from the user(without asking the question) and if any of the answers match, it increments the score and displays that finally. You need to alter that logic

Comment: @Lou44 - Check my edited answer. I think that should do the trick for you.

Comment: Great! That worked. Seems like those two scanner lines were messing it up completely! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It gives you an empty console because when you call the following line

```
System.out.print(T1.giveQuiz());
```

it first executes giveQuizz() witch awaits input from Scanner.

```
scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```

This means you first have to type an int, then something ending with newline and then the answers.

And I hope it's just a copy-paste error but the correct version way to access questionHolder is

```
questionHolder[i].answerCorrect(candidateAnswer)
```

not

```
questionHolder.answerCorrect(candidateAnswer)
```

Comment: Yeah it has the [i] in my source code. Not sure why it didn't copy onto here. I want it to print out each quiz question 1 by 1 and let the user answer them. When I type something the program crashes immediately

Answer (score 0):

The first thing `Quiz.giveQuiz()` does is waiting for your input. So it won't output anything until you type something into your terminal and hit return.

May be you want to add something like

```
 System.out.println("Please type a string and and integer and hit return");
```

This way the user (you ;-) ) knows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The above code does not compile because of the following statement: 
    if (questionHolder.answerCorrect(candidateAnswer))

it should be
    if (questionHolder[i].answerCorrect(candidateAnswer))

and execution begins at

```
 System.out.print(T1.giveQuiz());
```

when the execution begins you have to enter value

You are not getting any display because you are neither prompting anywhere to accept the answer nor might be entering that many number of values after which loop terminates and you get the score.